# use of libraries in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.2
```

these libraries cannot seem to work,and i can't use providers such as google,Facebook,twitter to login in my android project. I've tried to updated the android studio and now i'm using android studio 2.3.3 and i'm using:

```
    app:




compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

 minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1




 project:

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple) you need to add Google's Maven repository to your project-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle), add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I got the "could not find maven()" error as you had predicted but then when i went to Android Sdk manager to update Google Repository turns out i have the latest Google Repository 57 and there was no possible updated and i tried syncing again but still i had the same error

Comment: could not find maven() for arguments[build_aisc4laxiuorne4dk31r1fzq8h$_closure1$_closure5@23422bd4] on object of type org.gadle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Comment: this is what i have

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'                                                    
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+''
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
  
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: @lewisdylanNkuranga check the updated answer. you need to put maven url inside repositories instead of dependencies.

Comment: @lewisdylanNkuranga I tried it on my computer and it worked. Let me know if your issue is solved.

Comment: it works now allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        dependencies {
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
            }
        }
    }

}